# Overriding PHP settings in execution

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Working with WordPress, I often come across the same issue where hosting companies set the initial PHP settings for things like `upload_max_filesize` and `max_execution_time` to very low values. This becomes an issue when trying to import large demo content or migrate data from another server. I'm trying to find a way around it **using only a PHP script** (no FTP access, can't recompile PHP etc...). How can this be accomplished?

Here are a few things to consider:

- Using `ini_set()` only works for certain directive, which makes it useless in my case.
- Creating a `php.ini` or `php5.ini` file in the root of WordPress only works if PHP is set to scan this directory for additional ini files, which is rarely the case.
- Modifying the `.htaccess` file is an excellent way to achieve this, however, if PHP is run in "CGI mode" and not as an Apache module, this won't work.

Is there a solution that can work regardless of the host's settings? Is there a way to force PHP to scan an additional directory for `php.ini` files?

Comment: if you can't modify the php settings via ini_set/.ini file, then reverse the direction: upload a script which will DOWNLOAD the large file from another server. make it get the big stuff, instead of sending over the big stuff.

Comment: you have several solutions. pick one. there is no magical solution that fits every single use case. use ini_set on WP's index.php file so it's called on every page.

Comment: @MarcB I don't have that option. For example, some themes have their own built-in functionality to import demo content from the developer's server. The only way to make it work is to increase the settings values.

Comment: @Pamblam you can't use `ini_set` to change `max_input_vars` for example, which is often necessary.

Comment: an option would be to create an installer script which can detect those edge cases and provide helpful feedback (this is the host's admin responsibility at this point, not yours). Apart from that, you already know all possible workarounds.

Comment: @Calimero you are right about the fact that it is the admin's responsibility, but i'm trying to cut the process of contacting the hosting company and asking them to make changes (which sometimes can take a while...)